# Google Photos, when syncing photos from both default camera and WhatsApp, how to segregate on cloud?

Tags: sync, whatsapp-messenger, google-photos

I use Google Photos and turn on syncing of photos, taken from my default camera on my mobile phone and also syncing of WhatsApp images.

My question is: How can I have those synced to my google photo cloud storage in separate folders or albums? I don't want the photos that are synced to end up mixed between the images, taken on my mobile camera and WhatsApp images.

Or alternatively is there a way the synced photos are somehow tagged so that I can easily differentiate between the images taken with my camera or whatsapp?

Answer (score 0):

If you search for "wa" in the Photos app or the Google Photos website, it will show only the photos stored by WhatsApp.

If you click "Library" in the app, then click "Camera", it will show you only photos that were taken using your phone's camera. But as far as I can tell, that only works on your phone, or whatever device has the camera in question. This doesn't work when searching on the website, using my laptop, for photos I took with my phone.

If you search for the model of your phone ("Google Pixel 2" in my case) in the app or on the website, it will show you only photos you took using your phone. Or at least that is what it does for me.

I don't know of any way to make WhatsApp put its photos in its own folder, or to tag them so they can be searched for or excluded in any easier or simpler way. And no one else knows either, as far as I can tell from my research.